# cloud-init modify how netplan is formated on generation

Tags: netplan, cloud-init

By default cloud-init generates the following inside `50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - 145.239.202.202/32
            - 2001:41d0:800:226f::3/128
            gateway4: 51.89.172.254
            gateway6: 2001:41d0:800:22ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            match:
                macaddress: 02:00:00:ff:3b:ea
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 213.186.33.99
                search: []
            set-name: eth0
```

However I need to add routes: to the file to get the network working (OVH)

`50-cloud-init.yaml` :

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - 145.239.202.202/32
            - 2001:41d0:800:226f::3/128
            gateway4: 51.89.172.254
            gateway6: 2001:41d0:800:22ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
            match:
                macaddress: 02:00:00:ff:3b:ea
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 213.186.33.99
                search: []
            set-name: eth0
            routes:
            - to: 51.89.172.254/32
              via: 0.0.0.0
              scope: link
            - to: 2001:41d0:800:22ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
              scope: link
```

The only difference is there is the following added at the bottom:

```
        routes:
        - to: 51.89.172.254/32
          via: 0.0.0.0
          scope: link
        - to: 2001:41d0:800:22ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
          scope: link
```

How do I modify cloud-init template so that this is added by default so that if I re-run `cloud-init init` it will not remove it.

Comment: dhcp4: no and dhcp6: no are the defaults, so you don't need to specify (and use true/false). You can't use gateway4 and gateway6 when you use routes. match/macaddress is not necessary if you only have one ethernet interface. netplan will try to merge the two files anyway, so why not make one clear file that outlines your intent?

Comment: I can merge them but that's not all that's going on here I need to somehow change the way 50-cloud-init.yaml sets the IP addresses and add to it. For example routes: is not added by default.

Comment: Your routes are wrong anyway. Please see my answer. Report back.